# How can I apply a uniform format after finishing a presentation?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I realize that the slide master dictates a certain style on any new slides that are added to the presentation. However, users are free to override the style dictated by the slide master. Once all of the presentation content has been finalized, **is there a way to reapply the slide master** across the presentation in order to obtain uniform formatting (e.g. consistent bullets and fonts) on all slides prior to finalizing the presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerPoint 2003**

1. Go to Format > Slide Layout to open the Slide Layout task pane.
2. Select the slides you want to reapply the master layout to.
3. In the Slide Layout task pane, find the layout that you want to reapply.
4. Click the arrow on that layout and then select *Reapply Layout*.

**PowerPoint 2007 / 2010**

1. Select the slides you want to reapply the Slide Master formatting to.
2. On the Home tab of the ribbon, in the Slides section, click the *Reset* button.

   [image: Reset button in PowerPoint 2007]

Comment: Awesome! This is extremely helpful.

Comment: Note for future users: 
Although, the later versions of PowerPoint look somewhat different, the steps are identical to the PowerPoint 2007 / 2010 instructions above.